# Log-in with Google :Error while implementing (Auth2 not defined)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I want to integrate login with google into my website.I went throught the dicumnention and implemnted and got error which i am not able to solve despite of numerous googling.

I am using angularjs, so i have dia.html page where all script tag are mentioned so i wrote

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js?onload=start" async defer></script>
```

Next i wrote following code in my html page

```
<div class="box-home-login-forgot trans-slow-linear ">
<button id="signinButton" ng-click="signinButton();">Sign in with Google</button>
</div>
```

Next i wrote follwing code in controller.js

```
$scope.signinButton = function() {
                // signInCallback defined in step 6.
                auth2.grantOfflineAccess().then(signInCallback);
              };

    $scope.start = function(){
          gapi.load('auth2', function() {
            auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
              client_id: '486005552663-4nas7mg964ovaajmemn8ler2li5v57kg.apps.googleusercontent.com',
              // Scopes to request in addition to 'profile' and 'email'
              //scope: 'additional_scope'
            });
          });
        }
```

So initially start function was not calling despite of onload, so i manually wrote below code manually in my controller.

```
$scope.start();
```

After that i am constantly getting error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: auth2 is not defined
```

Can anyone please guide me where i am going wrong?? 
Just to include i have not written signincallback function as i was getting error.

Answer (score 0):

Since Html model was not binded into controller directly "Uncaught ReferenceError: auth2 is not defined" this error was coming. Later I shifted the code wrote  tag in HTML page and defined the function over there instead of a controller. It perfectly works.